# What's a word that describes an intent (only action)

Tags: single-word-requests

For example a person says "I want to call", but he doesn't mention the person he is going to call. So his intent is to call, but it's missing because an entity is missing (the person name/the number). So what do you call a --partial-- intent?

Comment: I would say that the sentence has an *implied direct object*.  I'm not sure how else to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, as mentioned in the comment above, by chasly, **the sentence has a concealed object.**

Semantically, I would call it **"volition"**.

> - "volition" (noun) -  an act of making a choice or decision [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volition)